# Django - custom representation of a field in templates

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I would like to have a field in my model which representation is automatically adjusted based in its value. Suppose I have this toy model:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_lenght=256)
    visits = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
```

I would like to write in my templates just `{{article.visits}}` and, if the value is (for example), 45, it will render "45", but if the value is 1233, it will print "1.2k".

This is simple using template filters for formating, but I would like to do it automatically in any case. is it possible? What do you suggest?

Comment: It's possible only using filters or tags in templates. Otherwise it will represent value like this also outside of templates.

Answer (score 3):

Add a property to the `Article` model:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    ...
    @property
    def visits_display(self):
        return self.visits if visits < 1000 else '%.1fk' % (self.visits/1000.0)
```

And use this property in the template:

```
{{ article.visits_display }}
```